# Can shorthand property names and computed property names be used simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use shorthand property names (ES2015) in conjunction with computed property names (also ES2015)? So for example...

```
const a = 'foo';
const o = {
    [a],
}
> o
> {
    "foo": "foo"
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want different output than what is given? If so, what should it be?

Comment: I think he's looking for the part of the specification which dictates this won't be parsed as he expects. I'll try to find. This is the closest I can think of offhand: `const o = {
    [a]: a,
}
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The [grammar for ES2015 Object Initializers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) do not allow for computed property names to be used alongside shorthands. Specifically, an *`ObjectLiteral`* is comprised of a *`PropertyDefinitionList`*. A *`PropertyDefinitionList`* is made up of *`PropertyDefinition`* s:

> #### [12.2.6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) Object Initializer
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> ObjectLiteral :
>   { }
>   { PropertyDefinitionList }
>   { PropertyDefinitionList, }
>
> PropertyDefinitionList :
>   PropertyDefinition
>   PropertyDefinitionList, PropertyDefinition
>
> PropertyDefinition :
>   IdentifierReference
>   CoverInitializedName
>   PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
>   MethodDefinition
> ```

The specific grammar that supports computed properties in object literals is *`PropertyName : AssignmentExpression`*, since *`PropertyName`* is defined as:

> ```
> PropertyName :
>   LiteralPropertyName
>   ComputedPropertyName
> ```

Thus, the grammar only supports `[computedProperty]: value`, since only *`PropertyName : AssignmentExpression`* is part of the grammar, not *`PropertyName`* itself.